# Highcharts Table y-axis maximum value

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts with table plugin and I want to set the value '10'in the y-axis of my line graph as the maximum value because the default chart detects the maximum value only so in case if 7 is the maximum value it will only show the 7 on the y-axis. I sit possible to set the y-axis maximum value to '10'?

I have tried the yAxis:{max: 10} but it seems its only available in the Highcharts js and not in the highcharts table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `data-graph-yaxis-max` in the options for HighchartTable, but you can set that maximum in general for charts:

```
$(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    yAxis: {
      max: 10
    }
  });
});
```